# REST API using Google Cloud Functions

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a general query regarding creating a simple REST API using Google Cloud Functions in Python. Is it best practice to create a HTTP function for each endpoint or create one function which handles all the endpoints?

Also is it possible to use a custom URL for the function e.g. /api/v1/pets/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote 2 articles on that topic, one in [Python](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-multiple-paths-in-cloud-functions-python-and-flask-fc6780e560d3) and the other in [Golang](https://medium.com/google-cloud/hack-use-cloud-functions-as-a-webserver-with-golang-42edc7935247).

But I can't recommend you to do that for real world workload, it's fun when you hack but not more. You can have a look to my [first article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1) that explain why I prefer Cloud Run to Cloud Function, and the local testing is the main argument that I can offer. Then portability.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, good reads. I was looking for examples in the Google documentation and didn't find my specific use case.

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud only supports one event definition per
function. However, you could handle multiple definition by using same sources or use one trigger which has a response to call another function that combines different kind of events. You can refer to [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions#resource-cloudfunction) GCP docs.

If you want to use a custom URL, you can check out [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-compute-engine-docker#python) since it acts as an API Gateway for Cloud Functions.

Comment: Great thank you. I will check it out.